# Unsupported feature 'assignment from non-constant source expression'

Tags: geometry, geolocation, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We are getting the below error when executing a standard script:

**Error:**
Unsupported feature 'assignment from non-constant source expression'.

**Script**
`set geo = (Select st_makepoint(-79.3810586,43.6562331));`

Comment: can you define "a standard script" a little be more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you SQL run by itself, that's a good start:

```
Select st_makepoint(-79.3810586,43.6562331);
```

| ST_MAKEPOINT(-79.3810586,43.6562331) |
| --- |
| { "coordinates": [ -7.938105860000000e+01, 4.365623310000000e+01 ], "type": "Point" } |

so a simple block with the dynamic type `let`:

```
begin
    let geo := (Select st_makepoint(-79.3810586,43.6562331));
    return geo;
end;
```

> 092228 (P0000): SQL compilation error: error line 2 at position 4
>
> variable 'GEO' cannot have its type inferred from initializer

so declaring the type ahead of time give:

```
declare
    geo GEOGRAPHY;
begin
    geo := (Select st_makepoint(-79.3810586,43.6562331));
    return geo;
end;
```

> 000603 (XX000): SQL execution internal error:
>
> Processing aborted due to error 300010:3443530546; incident 6816246.

that not good. but it might be related to the fact it's not in GA yet.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/variables.html#declaring-a-variable

> The data type of the variable. This can be:
>
> A SQL data type (except for GEOGRAPHY in this preview version).

so if you have the preview feature turned on the above might work for you..

But by "standard procedure" you mean a JavaScript Procedure:

```
create procedure f()
returns GEOGRAPHY
language javascript
as
$$
    var geo_sql = 'Select st_makepoint(-79.3810586,43.6562331)';
    
    var stmt1 = snowflake.createStatement( { sqlText: geo_sql } );

    var results1 = stmt1.execute();

    results1.next();
    
    return results1.getColumnValue(1);
$$
;
```

which we can call

```
call f();
```

| F |
| --- |
| { "coordinates": [ -7.938105860000000e+01, 4.365623310000000e+01 ], "type": "Point" } |

so that works..

Comment: I guess we will have to wait for the feature to be GA. Our use case is to use the geometry in downstream geospatial query which itself is another one line code. We wanted to avoid embedding the `st_makepoint` inside the query for that 0.01% optimization. However we would for now embed the `st_makepoint` inside the query.